# Create your own cookie banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I have a problem. I want to use a cookie banner for my website.
I have the problem that I built my website with Boostrap. And as soon as I insert this code into my real website, the banner is displayed at the top and no longer in the style.
So it's displayed above stored. How can I insert this code so that it works properly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cookie Consent Banner</title>
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cookiePopup" class="hide">
      <img src="cookie.png" />
      <p>
        Our website uses cookies to provide your browsing experience and
        relevant information. Before continuing to use our website, you agree &
        accept of our <a href="#">Cookie Policy & Privacy.</a>
      </p>
      <button id="acceptCookie">Accept</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f8ff;
}
#cookiePopup {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 42.85em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(5, 0, 31, 0.15);
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  padding: 2em 1.4em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
#cookiePopup img {
  display: block;
  width: 3.75em;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
#cookiePopup p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
}
#cookiePopup button {
  background-color: #6859fe;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em 1.4em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#cookiePopup a {
  color: #6859fe;
}
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2em;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
  #cookiePopup {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hide {
    bottom: 2em;
    right: 0;
  }
  .show {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

script.js

```js
let popUp = document.getElementById("cookiePopup");
//When user clicks the accept button
document.getElementById("acceptCookie").addEventListener("click", () => {
  //Create date object
  let d = new Date();
  //Increment the current time by 1 minute (cookie will expire after 1 minute)
  d.setMinutes(2 + d.getMinutes());
  //Create Cookie withname = myCookieName, value = thisIsMyCookie and expiry time=1 minute
  document.cookie = "myCookieName=thisIsMyCookie; expires = " + d + ";";
  //Hide the popup
  popUp.classList.add("hide");
  popUp.classList.remove("show");
});
//Check if cookie is already present
const checkCookie = () => {
  //Read the cookie and split on "="
  let input = document.cookie.split("=");
  //Check for our cookie
  if (input[0] == "myCookieName") {
    //Hide the popup
    popUp.classList.add("hide");
    popUp.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    //Show the popup
    popUp.classList.add("show");
    popUp.classList.remove("hide");
  }
};
//Check if cookie exists when page loads
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    checkCookie();
  }, 2000);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Home - Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:700&amp;display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Hero-Clean-Reverse.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/untitled.css">
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    />
</head>


<body id="page-top" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#mainNav" data-bs-offset="77" style="background: var(--bs-body-bg);font-family: Cabin, sans-serif;--bs-primary: #42DCA3;--bs-primary-rgb: 66,220,163;">
    <div id="cookiePopup" class="hide">
        <img src="assets/img/cookie.png" />
        <p>
         Our website uses cookies to provide your browsing experience and
        relevant information. Before continuing to use our website, you agree &
        accept of our <a href="#">Cookie Policy & Privacy.</a>
        </p>
        <button id="acceptCookie">Accept</button>
      </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Name</a><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" type="button" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" value="Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link"><a class="nav-link active" href="kontakt.html" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0);">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link"></li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
 
    </section>
    <section class="mb-5"></section>
    <footer class="text-center bg-dark" style="background: rgb(0,0,0);">
     ...
    </footer>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/smart-forms.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/grayscale.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A cookie notice like that is most likely in violation of any privacy regulation you are trying to comply with. So you should start by thinking about which regulation(s) you have or want to comply with in the first place. Then you should learn about what exactly that entails. Just having a button like that is definitely not enough. If you are trying to be GDPR-compliant for example, using Google fonts like that may already be a violation. You may learn more about GDPR on https://gdpr.eu/

Answer (score 0):

If your banner is displayed at the top and no longer in the style it could be some problem in the css;

Try commenting out these css one at a time, and by reloading the page you can see if one of them is the culprit:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Dark.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Hero-Clean-Reverse.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/untitled.css">
```

Alternatively, you can put the css "style.css" inside the html code and add !important

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Home - Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!--EDIT for coding-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:700&amp;display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Hero-Clean-Reverse.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/untitled.css">
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />-->
</head>
  
    <!-- Stylesheet on the html -->
    <style>
        * {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
          background-color: #f5f8ff;
        }
        #cookiePopup {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          position: absolute;
          font-size: 14px;
          width: 70vw;
          max-width: 42.85em;
          box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(5, 0, 31, 0.15);
          font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
          text-align: justify;
          line-height: 1.8em;
          padding: 2em 1.4em;
          border-radius: 6px;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        #cookiePopup img {
          display: block;
          width: 3.75em;
          transform: translateZ(0);
          position: relative;
          margin: auto;
        }
        #cookiePopup p {
          text-align: center;
          margin: 1.4em 0;
        }
        #cookiePopup button {
          background-color: #6859fe;
          border: none;
          color: #ffffff;
          font-size: 1.2em;
          padding: 1em 1.4em;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          margin: auto;
          border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #cookiePopup a {
          color: #6859fe;
        }
        .hide {
          visibility: hidden;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 2em;
        }
        .show {
          visibility: visible;
          bottom: 2em;
          right: 2em;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
          #cookiePopup {
            width: 100%;
          }
          .hide {
            bottom: 2em;
            right: 0;
          }
          .show {
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
          }
        }

    </style>
  <body id="page-top" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#mainNav" data-bs-offset="77" style="background: var(--bs-body-bg);font-family: Cabin, sans-serif;--bs-primary: #42DCA3;--bs-primary-rgb: 66,220,163;">
    <!--COOKIES-->
    <div id="cookiePopup" class="hide">
      <img src="cookie.png" />
      <p>
        Our website uses cookies to provide your browsing experience and
        relevant information. Before continuing to use our website, you agree &
        accept of our <a href="#">Cookie Policy & Privacy.</a>
      </p>
      <button id="acceptCookie">Accept</button>
    </div>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Name</a><button data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" type="button" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" value="Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link"><a class="nav-link active" href="kontakt.html" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0);">Kontakt</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link"></li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Section-->
    <section class="mb-5"></section>
    
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="text-center bg-dark" style="background: rgb(0,0,0);">
        ...
    </footer>
    
    <!-- Script -->
    <script>
        let popUp = document.getElementById("cookiePopup");
        //When user clicks the accept button
        document.getElementById("acceptCookie").addEventListener("click", () => {
          //Create date object
          let d = new Date();
          //Increment the current time by 1 minute (cookie will expire after 1 minute)
          d.setMinutes(2 + d.getMinutes());
          //Create Cookie withname = myCookieName, value = thisIsMyCookie and expiry time=1 minute
          document.cookie = "myCookieName=thisIsMyCookie; expires = " + d + ";";
          //Hide the popup
          popUp.classList.add("hide");
          popUp.classList.remove("show");
        });
        //Check if cookie is already present
        const checkCookie = () => {
          //Read the cookie and split on "="
          let input = document.cookie.split("=");
          //Check for our cookie
          if (input[0] == "myCookieName") {
            //Hide the popup
            popUp.classList.add("hide");
            popUp.classList.remove("show");
          } else {
            //Show the popup
            popUp.classList.add("show");
            popUp.classList.remove("hide");
          }
        };
        //Check if cookie exists when page loads
        window.onload = () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            checkCookie();
          }, 2000);
        };
    </script>
    
        <footer class="text-center bg-dark" style="background: rgb(0,0,0);">
         ...
        </footer>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--EDIT for coding-->
        <script src="assets/js/smart-forms.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/grayscale.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[In my browser works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akHMv.png)